React-native expo deep linking
I am trying to capture path and navigating to MagicLinkSignup screen.  how can i achieve it with expo? with expo cli i can test it with npx uri-scheme open exp://192.168.39.115:8081/--/MagicLinkSignup/ eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsIn.
But after making eas build i am unable to open with link.


import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import * as Linking from 'expo-linking';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import BottomNavigation from '../components/navigation/bottomNavigation';
import { useUser } from '../lib/context/userContext';

import RootscreenStack from '../components/navigation/rootStack';
export default function Navigation() {

  const { user } = useUser();
  const prefix = Linking.createURL('/');
  
  const config = {
    screens: {
      MagicLinkSignup: {
        path: "MagicLinkSignup/:token",
        parse: (token: String) => `${token}`
      },
      AcceptLeaseByLink: {
        path: "AcceptLeaseByLink/:token",
        parse: (token: String) => `${token}`
      },
      Splash: "Splash"

    }
  }
  const linking = {
    prefixes: [prefix, 'https://', 'rentcreek://', 'localhost'],
    config
  };
  return (
    <NavigationContainer linking={linking} fallback={<Text>Loading...         </Text>}>
      {user?.role == "landlord" || user?.role == "admin" || user?.role ==           "superadmin" ?
        <BottomNavigation />
        :
        <RootscreenStack />
      }
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}



app.json


expo {
...
   scheme: "myapp"
}



My url looks like this: myapp://MagicLinkSignup/eyJhbGcierew4f

Do you have MagicLinkSignup route in your navigation stack?

@user18309290 yes i have

Its working with ios but not in android
